# restoring dropdown selected values in c# after refresh by retrieving values from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a dropdownlist in my webpage which is outside the gridview and I have added automatic refresh. My problem is that I`m unable to retain the selected value in dropdownlist after the refresh. It goes to the default settings in the dropdown. Please help.

---

Thanks a lot for replying..

part of my code goes this way....

```
page_load(...)
{
 Refresh 
 if(!IsPostBack)
 {
   //calling my function which includes databind..
    myfunction();
 }
}
```

i tried the same code as you people suggested but its not working..
even now after refresh, the default values appear in dropdownlist

Comment: is the dropdown created dynamically ??. Show some code first

Comment: You need to use  `Page.IsPostBack`. check out this [Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848732/dropdownlist-postback-to-default-selected-value

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess your `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBindGridView(); // loads the datasource of the grid and calls gridView1.DataBind();
    DataBindDropDown(); // loads the datasource of the dropdown and calls dropDown1.DataBind();
}
```

Do not reload all on every postback, just if `!(IsPostBack)`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBindGridView();   
        DataBindDropDown();  
    }
}
```

If you need to refresh your GridView don't use `Page_Load` but the appropriate event handler. If you use an [ASP.NET `Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx) to reload your page periodically to refresh the grid, use it's [`Tick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.tick.aspx) event.

```
protected void GridRefreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBindGridView();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to implement something like this in your page_load handler:

```
if (IsPostback) return;    
//here populate the dropdown
```